# How to calculate mass from time dilation and radius?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, time-dilation

I'm new to this site and I'm been searching the internet all over for this solution. I'm looking for an equation, that if given the time dilation at the surface of an object and its radius, it will allow me to calculate the mass of the object.

However, the current way of calculating time dilation (dτ/dt) does not work for my model and is not what I am looking for.

I'm looking for the equation to calculate the mass of an object if given its radius and the amount of the time dilation based on a range of **0.0 - 1.0**. Where 1 would be infinite time dilation.

To derive this new time dilation scale I use the formula $1-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}}$ where v is the escape velocity in the percentage of c.

For example, if the escape velocity is **.886 c** the object has a time dilation of **0.5363147619**

$1-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-.886^2/1^2}}}$ = 0.5363147619

Based off this scale (0.0 - 1.0) and given the radius of an object I'm looking for the object's mass.

To calculate the time dilation without the range **0.0 - 1.0** it's

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-.886^2/1^2}}$ = 2.15

This does not work for me. I need the output of mass from the unknown equation using the input time dilation range of **0.0 - 1.0**

Thank you.

Comment: If 1.0 is supposed to represent infinite time dilation, what is 0.1 supposed to represent? Are you aware that time dilation is conventionally expressed as a number between 1 and infinity, or between 0 and 1?

Comment: Your first formula actually gives a *negative* number, which means it is wrong. Moving clocks do not run backwards.

Comment: sorry, I just updated and corrected the post. The range is 0.0 - 1.0

Comment: Do you know the escape velocity in terms of M and R?

Comment: I only know in terms of time dilation and radius. I'm looking for the mass

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity

Comment: Is this the correct way to rewrite the escape velocity equation if I'm looking for mass. $M=\sqrt{\frac{vr}{2G}}$

Comment: No. You didn’t solve the first equation on the Wikipeda page for M properly, but this is not a site to teach algebra.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. Instead, edit the original question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453833/time-dilation-to-mass-equation